# How much benefit will I get if I add another 4GB ram to my Laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, motherboard

I am using ASUS K55A-series laptop.

Specification:

- Intel® Core™ i3 3110M Processor ( 3rd generation)
- DDR3 1600 MHz SDRAM, 2 x SO-DIMM socket for expansion up to 8 GB
  SDRAM
- Integrated Intel® HD Graphics 4000
- HDD: 750GB 5400/7200

This is showing that it is expandable to 8 GB. But I am fearing for core i3 processor.

If I add another 4GB ram how much benefit will I get considering this processor?

**update:** I mainly use Linux and secondarily windows 10. Mostly I have to run software and web development tools such as AndroidStudio, PHPStorm, Netbeans ( this is as per comment.)

Comment: Depends on 2 things which you haven't specified: your operating system and what type of software / workload you intend to run on it. If you post this  information you might get an answer.

Comment: @Lqueryvg I updated the question.

Comment: 4GB is enough for common tasks. Adding more than enough won't increase performance unless performance is limited by amount of memory you have. But as you said you run android studio, I had say increase it to 8GB :) Assuming you browse internet, run android studio and run emulator at the same time.

Comment: @MarkEvans, yes. I have to do these at the same time.

Comment: Linux is good at memory management, so I'd say the test is start doing some "normal" work on your Linux system and then check `free` or other tools to see how much if any swap is being used.  If you are using swap, then more RAM will help.  Also consider if you want to use any virtualization technologies, whatever RAM you assign will be blocked from other use even if your virtualized OS isn't using all that it was allocated at the time

Answer (score 2):

After some Google-Fu research [Intel i3-3110M specifications](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/50178/intel-core-i3-380m-processor-3m-cache-2-53-ghz.html) as specified on this page that it's expandable to 32 GB of RAM , and one important thing to notice that it supports flex memory access

[image: Intel specifies that it supports flex memory access]

which is self explanatory and also according to [this link on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Operation) describes the dual channel arch / flex memory mode:

> Capacity (e.g. 1024 MB). Certain Intel chipsets support different capacity chips in what they call Flex Mode: the capacity that can be matched is run in dual-channel, while the remainder runs in single-channel.

so on this basis, yeah you can use RAM with different capacities together, and in similar way you can also look for any other processor you want to know about. :)

Answer (score 1):

Accorfing to [i3 3110 specifications](http://ark.intel.com/products/65700/Intel-Core-i3-3110M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_40-GHz) you can use up to 32 GB. So you don't need to worry about your i3. I had 8gb with i3 of the 2nd generation and had no issues.

What benefit you'll get depends mainly on the tasks you do and software you use. Additional 4 GB will be good if you work a lot with praphics or video processing. You might not see any difference if you're only surfing, typing texts and watching videos. Anyway, remember: there is no such thing as too much RAM!

You have an integrated graphic card which uses your RAM so your real available RAM is less than 4GB now. So I would recommend to expand your memory anyway. But make sure it's of the same type that you already have. Or you better buy a 8GB kit (2x 4GB) and sell your current 4GB.

Seeing updated question: Considering that a single Virtual Device in Android Studio might use up to 2 GB it's highly recommended that you add another 4 GB.

Answer (score 0):

You **will** almost certainly feel the difference.  With 4GB RAM your web browser will be open to read some documentation and you will switch back to Android Studio and some things won't respond for a moment as bits of the virtual memory page back in from swap.

Linux will also make good use of any extra RAM you provide it, caching any recently used files so that re-reads get faster and so forth.  The whole experience just gets smoother.

Two examples: My son has 8GB and regularly sees problems swapping between browser and Minecraft.  I have 16GB in my own laptop and it is currently all actively used by the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in graphic/animation/video performance of the computer.

Only thing it will do is allow you to seamlessly use much more software simultaneously than before. It adds up space to run more programs simultaneously. This will eliminate the hanging computer situation, if you experience that.

As you use Android Studio, I would recommend more RAM, as much as you can afford and your PC can handle. This will make the experience smoother, as Android Studio with Chrome(any browser) can use some decent amount of RAM.

Comment: Not exactly true. If you are running a single program that pushes your RAM usage to over 75 or 80% or so, then then that program will likely run faster with more RAM in the machine, even if you're not running anything else at the time.

Comment: I am saying the same thing,  but if the program does not run fine with low RAM,  like a high graphics game. It will not run decently even with 16 Gigs RAM.

Comment: Not necessarily, Rahul. If the program is limited by the graphics capability of the machine, then yes. But if the reason the program does not "run fine with low RAM" is lack of RAM, then more RAM will help. As I said, the way to tell is to look at the available RAM while the program is running. The page fault and, especially, hard fault rate are also useful to look at.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And if graphics are an issues, then RAM is futile. I can say more RAM is useful but will not affect the graphics performance of computer.

Comment: That's still not necessarily true. What we see as "graphic performance" may in fact be constrained by RAM. If a program needs a large working set (the in-RAM subset of its virtual address space) to keep the graphics card well-fed with updates, and there isn't room for all of it in the RAM that's avaialble, the user's perception will be "graphics performance is poor" even though the real problem is exxcessive paging caused by lack of RAM.

Comment: can you please point-out, what graphic performance is constrained by RAM, if RAM is according to the recommended suggestions of the Game/software provider? It better be constrained by GPU than RAM, if you have atleast the recommended stuff.

Comment: The "Game/software provider" has only limited idea of how the software will be used and in particular cannot anticipate the effects of add-on modules ("mods" for a game, or plug-ins to say a graphics editor, video editor, 3d modeling app, etc.) or of the size or complexity of the data set being manipulated. If you observe limited available RAM, a high page fault rate, or (most critical) a high hard page fault rate (that means page faults that have to be resolved to disk), performance (not just graphics!) will very likely benefit from more RAM. This is performance optimization 101 stuff.

Comment: Don't talk about page faults here, there are some algorithms which perform worse for a higher amount of RAM.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've only been doing performance analysis on virtual memory OSs since, oh, 1981 or so. The hard fault rate is an absolutely essential metric. (And I'll talk about what i please.)